# Add a background Image for ImageButton

Tags: android, xml-layout

I am new to android and xml and was trying to add a background image to an ImageButton when selected/focused in xml. First of all I'd like to know if it is possible if yes then here is what I am doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
        <selector >
            <item
                android:state_focused="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/image_button_bg"/>
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now the problem is I don't see any changes. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selector is what you are looking for. You can put different images for each state.

res/drawable/my_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

and in your xml layout file add it to background of your imagebutton.

```
    android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
```

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the Question I am using selector but its nor working

Comment: but don't use it in layer-list. Just selector would be fine.

Comment: Well if I delete layer-list The application crashes and does not give any reason in logcat why it is crashing

Comment: Alright this worked... but why doesn't layer-list allow background?

Comment: layer list works exactly like what it should be, you can put images or shapes on top of each other and you get one output. Selector is designed for the situations like this.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear but the question is that since I am using selector in layer-list why isn't it working? Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: layerlist accept one single item for each item element which is a child of selector. Simply you can't put selector in layerlist. Layerlist and statelist serves for different needs.